# Как создать QGridLayout в ячейках QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Как программно создать в ячейках таблицы QTableView сетку QGridLayout, в которой размещены лейблы QLable?

Comment: Надо сделать соответствующий виджет (который с метками), который, в свою очередь, создавать и рисовать в методе paint  в классе-наследнике QStyledItemDelegate и затем, все это добавить в QTableView.

Answer (score 0):

делал недавно что то похожее , только не в табличном варианте , вдруг вам поможет

```
int main() {

TabsView start_window {
    "parentLayout",
    "pParent",
    {
        {"QLineEdit", "QLabel", "Stretch"},
        {"QLineEdit", "QLabel", "Stretch"},
        {"QLineEdit", "QLabel", "Stretch"},
        {"Stretch", "QPushButton"}
    }
};

TabsView setting_window {
    "parentLayout",
    "pParent",
    {
        {"QLineEdit1", "QLabel1", "Stretch1"},
        {"QLineEdit1", "QLabel1", "Stretch1"},
        {"QLineEdit1", "QLabel1", "Stretch1"},
        {"Stretch1", "QPushButton1"}
    }
};

auto lm = Layout(start_window);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lm._model.elements.size(); ++i){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < lm._model.elements[i].size(); ++j){
        cout << lm._model.elements[i][j] << " : ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


auto lm1 = Layout(setting_window);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lm1._model.elements.size(); ++i){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < lm1._model.elements[i].size(); ++j){
        cout << lm1._model.elements[i][j] << " : ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

вывод в консоли

```
Layout created
QLineEdit : QLabel : Stretch :
QLineEdit : QLabel : Stretch :
QLineEdit : QLabel : Stretch :
Stretch : QPushButton :
Layout created
QLineEdit1 : QLabel1 : Stretch1 :
QLineEdit1 : QLabel1 : Stretch1 :
QLineEdit1 : QLabel1 : Stretch1 :
Stretch1 : QPushButton1 :
```

вместо cout можете использовать деиствие по добавлению элемента в табличные поля

Comment: вот здесь проект кодеблок https://mega.nz/#!3rpG1I4a!_RGDg67x7j7lIkCnt0eRoVZVtC_9vMYAe2ZSkeY80nI